# Form Submission code check

Tags: php

The Contact page which has form submission, https://photos.app.goo.gl/GpbWvks2Y3SjwmX58 is not being executed. I tried various solutions from other questions that's already been asked but had no luck.
The .php file is in the Contacts folder along with the Contacts/index.html page.
Some expert help would be much appreciated.

Here's the Javascript on the HTML page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('spc').value = '755fd9ccedf916b2cd08bb7be88691dd';</script>
<form name="enquiry" method="post" action="infosemantic-enquiryform1.php" class="form" id="form">
    <p class="input_field">
        <label class="field">First Name:</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="name_box" id="name" value="" size="35">
    </p>
    <p class="input_field">
        <label class="field">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="lastname" type="text" class="name_box" id="lastname" value="" size="35">
    </p>
    <p class="input_field">
        <label class="field">Title:</label>
        <input name="title" type="text" class="name_box" id="title" value="" size="35">
    </p>
    <p class="input_field">
        <label class="field">Company:</label>
        <input value="" name="company" class="name_box" size="35" type="text">
    </p>
    <p class="input_field">
        <label class="field">E-mail Address:</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" class="name_box" id="email" value="" size="35">
    </p>
    <p class="input_field">
        <label class="field">Message:</label>
        <textarea name="Message" id="csinbr" cols="45" rows="5" class="name_box2" w></textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="btn"><input name="Subject" value="Enquiry from DSR Power" type="hidden">
        <input name="Submit" value="Submit " class="sbm" type="submit">
        <input name="Reset" value="Clear Form" class="sbm" type="reset">
    </p>
    <font face="Verdana" size="2">
        <font face="Verdana" size="2">
            <input name="form_name" value="rajforever2" type="hidden">
        </font>
        <input name="userid" value="webindia" type="hidden">
    </font>
</form>
</div>
```

```
$message = "<html><body><table align='center' boarder='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='2'  style='font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#CCCCFF;color:#000000;;border:double'>";
$message .= "<tr><td align='left'><b> Name  </b></td><td>:</td><td>".$_POST['name']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td align='left'><b>Last Name </b></td><td>:</td><td>".$_POST['lastname']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td align='left'><b>Title  </b></td><td>:</td><td>".$_POST['title']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td align='left'><b>Company </b></td><td>:</td><td>".$_POST['company']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td align='left'><b>Email </b></td><td>:</td><td>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "<tr><td align='left'><b>Message</b></td><td>:</td><td>".$_POST['Message']."</td></tr>";
$message .= "</table></body></html>";


/*to avoid spam mails in contact form*/
// Select if you want to check form for standard spam text
$SpamCheck = "Y"; // Y or N
$SpamReplaceText = "*content removed*";
// Error message prited if spam form attack found
$SpamErrorMessage = "<p align=\"center\"><font color=\"red\">Malicious code content detected.</font><br><b>Your IP Number of <b>".
                    getenv("REMOTE_ADDR").
                    "</b> has been logged.</b></p>";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['comments'];
if ($SpamCheck == "Y") {
    // Check for Website URL's in the form input boxes as if we block website URLs from the form,
    // then this will stop the spammers wastignt ime sending emails
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$name")) {
        echo "$SpamErrorMessage";
        exit();
    }
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$email")) {
        echo "$SpamErrorMessage";
        exit();
    }
    if (preg_match("/http/i", "$msg")) {
        echo "$SpamErrorMessage";
        exit();
    }

    // Patterm match search to strip out the invalid charcaters, this prevents the mail injection spammer
    $pattern = '/(;|\||`|>|<|&|^|"|'."\n|\r|'".'|{|}|[|]|\)|\()/i'; // build the pattern match string

    $name = preg_replace($pattern, "", $name);
    $email = preg_replace($pattern, "", $email);
    $msg = preg_replace($pattern, "", $msg);

    // Check for the injected headers from the spammer attempt
    // This will replace the injection attempt text with the string you have set in the above config section
    $find = ["/bcc\:/i", "/Content\-Type\:/i", "/cc\:/i", "/to\:/i"];
    $email = preg_replace($find, "$SpamReplaceText", $email);
    $name = preg_replace($find, "$SpamReplaceText", $name);
    $msg = preg_replace($find, "$SpamReplaceText", $msg);

    // Check to see if the fields contain any content we want to ban
    if (stristr($name, $SpamReplaceText) !== false) {
        echo "$SpamErrorMessage";
        exit();
    }
    if (stristr($msg, $SpamReplaceText) !== false) {
        echo "$SpamErrorMessage";
        exit();
    }

    // Do a check on the send email and subject text
    if (stristr($to, $SpamReplaceText) !== false) {
        echo "$SpamErrorMessage";
        exit();
    }
    if (stristr($subject, $SpamReplaceText) !== false) {
        echo "$SpamErrorMessage";
        exit();
    }
}
/*End*/

$headers = "From: $_POST[email]"."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc:bharath@briofactors.com'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1; format=flowed\n';
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    header("location:thanks.html");
}
```

Comment: What is actually not executing ?

Comment: Is the `thanks.html` file inside the folder `Contacts`?

Comment: It was previously set (by someone else) to send inquiries from the website to a particular email id and doesn't seem to function. Any help much appreciated.Thanks

Comment: No, the thanks.html file is not in the Contacts folder

Comment: did you check the server logs for errors ? if the page does not redirect, it probably means that there is an error before

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Part of the problem is solved. So now looks like the Form submission is being executed as inquiries are being received from the website to the email id. But the error page still shows up after clicking on the submit button. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: The error page says " Not Found [CFN #0005]"

Comment: Thanks. Placing the Thanks.html folder solved the problem.